# How to install an OpenLDAP service running on non default port?

Tags: windows, service, installation, openldap

I have a production LDAP server running on 389 and I want to install another OpenLDAP for test purpose on port 10389.

I am wondering how to install the OpenLDAP daemon as a windows service that will run on another port than 389.

Note: I cannot use the `slapd install` as I already have this service installed...

Comment: Which OpenLDAP? Symas? Userbooster? Cygwin?

Comment: I tried with userbooster. Does it change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I installed [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/) that can run any kind of executable as a service.

I have created a batch file with the appropriate options and now I have Open LDAP running as a service on a non default port.